# Tkinter - TopLevel Window Not Scrolling

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar

I am creating a simple app for gym staff to use which allows them to do various things, one of which is open a membership form where they can sign up users.

When I open the membership form (toplevel) the window appears just fine and I can see all the widgets, if I expand the window size down I can see the other widgets are there. I can hover over the scrollbar and scroll it down with my mousewheel but the actual form itself doesnt move down so I can see the bottom of the form. I've tried to see any other questions like mine but couldnt find any which gave me a solution for my issue.

This is part of my main code currently:

```
from tkinter import ttk, Button, Toplevel
from city_gym_signup import MembershipForm


class CityGymApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("City Gym 2023 Ltd")
        self.root.geometry("1400x500")
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.conn = dbOps.db_connect("city_gym_db.db")
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        membership_button = Button(
            main_tab,
            text="Membership Form",
            font=config.NORMAL_FONT,
            width=20,
            bg=config.BG_PURPLE,
            fg="black",
            activebackground=config.ACTIVE_GREY,
            command=self.open_signup_form
        )

    def open_signup_form(self):
        signup_window = Toplevel(self.root)
        signup_window.title("Membership Form")
        signup_window.geometry("1400x500")
        
        signup_form_instance = MembershipForm(signup_window)
        signup_frame = signup_form_instance.create_membership_form(signup_window)

        signup_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

        # Configure the scrollable area within the Toplevel window
        signup_window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        signup_window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        signup_window.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = CityGymApp(root)
    app.root.mainloop()
    app.conn.close()
```

and this is the start of my signup module:

```
from tkinter import Label, Canvas, Scrollbar

class MembershipForm:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def create_membership_form(self, parent):

        membership_frame = Frame(self.parent)

        canvas, scrollable_frame = self.scroll(membership_frame)

        self.create_text_inputs()

        # Update the scrollable area
        scrollable_frame.update_idletasks()

        # Configure columns in the scrollable area to expand
        for col_num in range(4):
            scrollable_frame.grid_columnconfigure(col_num, weight=1)

        # Set scrollable_frame as a child of membership_frame
        scrollable_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        # Configure canvas scroll region
        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

        # Configure the row containing the canvas to expand vertically
        membership_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

        # Configure columns in the main window to expand evenly
        for col_num in range(4):
            membership_frame.grid_columnconfigure(col_num, weight=1)

        return membership_frame

    def scroll(self, membership_frame):
        # Creating a Canvas to contain the form.
        canvas = Canvas(
            membership_frame,
            width=1000,
            height=1558
        )
        canvas.grid(
            row=4,
            column=0,
            columnspan=4,
            sticky="NSEW"
        )

        # Creating a scroll bar and linking to Canvas.
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(membership_frame, command=canvas.yview)
        scrollbar.grid(
            row=4,
            column=4,
            sticky="ns"
        )
        canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        # Creating a frame inside the canvas to hold the form elements.
        self.scrollable_frame = Frame(
            canvas,
            bg=config.BG_WHITE
        )

        canvas.create_window(
            (0, 0),
            window=self.scrollable_frame,
            anchor="nw"
        )

        # Function to scroll with mouse wheel.
        def on_canvas_scroll(event):
            canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * (event.delta // 120), "units")

            canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", on_canvas_scroll)

        # Function to scroll with keyboard arrow keys.
        def on_canvas_key_scroll(event):
            if event.keycode == 38:  # Up arrow key
                canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units")
            elif event.keycode == 40:  # Down arrow key
                canvas.yview_scroll(1, "units")

            canvas.bind_all("<Up>", on_canvas_key_scroll)
            canvas.bind_all("<Down>", on_canvas_key_scroll)

        return canvas, self.scrollable_frame

    # Create text inputs for user data.
    def create_text_inputs(self):

        customer_details_label = Label(
            self.scrollable_frame,
            text="Customer Details",
            font=config.HEADING_FONT,
            bg=config.BG_WHITE
        )
        customer_details_label.grid(
            row=5,
            column=0,
            sticky=W,
            padx=20,
            pady=10
        )
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing here? All my widgets are inside the scrollable_frame, which is inside the canvas (this should be big enough to fit all the widgets with the size I have made it), which is inside the membership_frame and I have tried so many things. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You should not call `scrollable_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")` since `scrollable_frame` has been put in the canvas using `canvas.create_window(...)`.  Also you need to update `scrollregion` of the canvas whenever `scrollable_frame` is resized

Comment: @acw1668 thank you so much! Can you see why it wont scroll with the mousewheel when not on the scrollbar or with the up/down keys by any chance?

Comment: Note that the bindings are called inside the callbacks of the bindings, so the bindings are not called actually because the callbacks are never called.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @acw1668 for both responses :)

acw1668 - You should not call scrollable_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew") since scrollable_frame has been put in the canvas using canvas.create_window(...). Also you need to update scrollregion of the canvas whenever scrollable_frame is resized.

Follow up question from me - Can you see why it wont scroll with the mousewheel when not on the scrollbar or with the up/down keys by any chance?

acw1668 - Note that the bindings are called inside the callbacks of the bindings, so the bindings are not called actually because the callbacks are never called.